# Return JSON in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am consuming a Odata end point in my web API and trying return JSON response from the API.My controller is like below

```
public class GetEmployeesDEVController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<EmployeeDTO.RootObject> Get()
    {
        EmployeeDTO.RootObject returnObj = new EmployeeDTO.RootObject();
        var responsedata = "";
        using (var client_Core = new HttpClient())
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
                Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL_Core);
                client_Core.BaseAddress = uri;
                client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray_Core));
                string core_URL = BaseURL_Core;
                var response = client_Core.GetAsync(core_URL).Result;
                responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeDTO.RootObject>(responsedata);
        return returnObj;
    }
```

Here EmployeeDTO is the model class for the Odata response. When I call my API it returns nulls and dont return any data. But the `responsedata` holds JSON that has data. Screenshot of `responsedata` and `returnObj` is below

[image]
 [image]

I am not sure if I am missing anything here. All I need to get from my API is the exact response from the Odata endpoint that is stored in `responsedata`

Comment: Shouldn’t you deserialize the object instead of serializing it?

Comment: @OrElse Yes I am Deserializing it was mistake when I pasted as I was trying to troubleshoot the issue. I have the above behaviour while deserializing

Comment: In your case, I would separate the issues like pasting as classes the responsedata in visual studio and then trying to deserialize on it.

Comment: Check this line : `client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));` you will get json value in `responsedata` then why you are trying to convert in json again, just `return responsedata;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your global.asax

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSetting=
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```